# I'm locked out of WordPress after using the WPS Hide Login plugin

Tags: wordpress, content-management-system, password-protection, wordpress-login

I have a WordPress site which I've built. I've installed and used the WPS Hide Login plugin to help with security (if that helps at all).

I've left the values of the login URL the default values which I believe are `/login`

When I go to `/login`, the login screen comes up, I enter my credentials which are correct, and after a few seconds I get redirected to the home page of the website rather than being redirected to my dashboard. I then go back to `/login` and it asks me to login again.

Nothing comes up to show me that I've successfully logged in. I've tried disabling the plugin via FTP too but that doesn't make much difference. I'm completely locked out!

Can someone please help me?

Thanks!

Comment: Try logging in using a different browser and see if that helps.

Comment: Happened to me also. Have you tried /wp-admin after it redirects you to homepage? BTW, i ended up ditching the plugin and write my own code to mask my login page url.

Answer (score 8):

The most easy option to see or change the admin dashboard URL with the *WPS Hide Login* plugin without access to the admin dashboard is from the database.

- Use tool such as phpMyAdmin and browse through your application database in the "*_option*" table then navigate to the "*whl_page*" row when you will be able to see the currently set admin login URL.

  ```
  SELECT option_value FROM wp_options WHERE option_name='whl_page';
  ```
- You can deactivate the plugin from FTP as or file manager (if the hoster provider such).
- Another option is to use WP CLI tool with the next command from the root directory of your WordPress instance:

  wp plugin deactivate wps-hide-login

**NOTE:** In order to use the WP CLI tool, please note that the same should be installed on the server. If you write the command and the terminal respond is:

```
-bash: wp: command not found
```

Or something similar ending with "*command not found*" this means that the tool in question is not installed. In this case you will be unable to use the WP CLI tool or you can ask your hosting provider to install this tool for you.

While searching for similar topics I found quite many people reporting such issue from the plugin in question. This is why, I would recommend you to consider using another plugin with such functionality or contact the plugin developers, so they could provide more information on why this problem occur at first place.

Comment: Hi there, Thanks for the answer! What should the default whl_page value be? Currently it is set to login (assuming that's left over from the wps hide login plugin within the database).I have also disabled the plugin by adding an underscore at the beginning, but wp-admin still not working.

Comment: Hello, I am sorry to understand that the issue is not resolved. The "_whl_page_" row is from the WPS Hide Login plugin and the default value for the same is "_login_".

When the plugin is deactivated by changing its name you should be able to access the admin dashboard login with **yourdomain.com/wp-login.php** or **yourdomain.com/wp-admin**. Also what do you mean by not working? Are you being redirected to another URL or you are able to see some message in your browser?

Answer (score 3):

You can disable the plugin by renaming the plugins directory:

```
wp-content/plugins/plugin-name
```

to

```
wp-content/plugins/_plugin-name
```

And then login by appending /wp-admin/ to your URL.

If you choose a strong password (20 or more characters), then it is not neccessary to hide the login.