# Uninstall WPS Hide Login

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I was working on a project (just for fun) some weeks ago and I`ve installed the WPS Hide Login for security purposes. Unfortunately, I`ve forgot the admin address and I would like to know how to uninstall this plugin without accessing the control panel (with I do not have access).

It`s possible to do only accessing the phpMyadmin?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I'm locked out of WordPress after using the WPS Hide Login plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58773155/im-locked-out-of-wordpress-after-using-the-wps-hide-login-plugin)

Comment: Not really, I can't even access the login page, not because it doesn't work but because I forgot the correct URL

Comment: Read the answers. It specifically mention getting the url from phpmyadmin

Comment: It says to check in "_option" and then in "whl_page" row, but the only row with "page" it's posts_per_page, which is not the case. I'm checking if a find more informations...........
I can take a print if you want

Comment: I've undeleted my answer that's taken from the project git page. If that still doesn't work, explain which plugin you're using

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Either go to your MySQL database and look for the value of rwl_page in the options table, or remove the rename-wp-login folder from your plugins folder, log in through wp-login.php and reinstall the plugin.

From [the project git page](https://github.com/ellatrix/rename-wp-login)

Comment: That part `remove the rename-wp-login folder from your plugins folder, log in through wp-login.php and reinstall the plugin` worked for me, thank you!